# Sign Xamarin iOS service extension with mbuild

Tags: ios, xamarin, msbuild, provisioning-profile, visual-studio-app-center

Xamarin cross platform app with a notification service extension.

When I build the app in Visual Studio with "Archive app for publishing", then sign manually the iOS project AND the service extension with the ad-hoc profiles (for the example), and upload to AppCenter for distribution, it's installing fine on our test devices.

However, the company process involve TeamCity for building the app automatically at each branch push using a custom script (msbuild)

Was working fine until i added the service extension. Since that, with the same script, the app builds fine but at instal from AppCenter i get "App integrity couldn't be verified".

I suppose there is something wrong with the tricky iOS signing process but can't figure out what.

Do i need to build the service extension separately using msbuild commands, or is it included in the ios project build as they are linked?
All the `<CodesignKey>` and `<CodesignProvision>` tags containing the right names in the .csproj files.
The configuration mappings are well configured.

The build script look like this:

```
msbuild Project.iOS.sln /t:Build

msbuild Project/Project.iOS/Project.iOS.csproj

msbuild /p:Configuration="Ad-Hoc" \
/p:Platform="iPhone" \
/p:IpaPackageDir="%env.PackageDirectory%" \
/t:Build Project.iOS.sln
```

Comment: Have you tried adding the `--deep` flag for the signing arguments?

Comment: @Cheesebaron just tried to add it in the ios project, then ios + service extension, no change on the outcome.

That's what it adds in the csproj: `<CodesignExtraArgs>--deep</CodesignExtraArgs>`